# Execution of TSQL statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am aware of the sequence of the execution of SQL statements but I still want to make sure few things with the help of SQL experts here. I have a big SQL query which returns thousands of rows. Here is the minimized version of the query which I wrote and think that it is correct.

```
Select * 
from property 
inner join tenant t on (t.hproperty = p.hmy **and p.hmy = 7**)
inner join commtenant ct on ct.htenant = t.hmyperson
where 1=1
```

My colleague says that above query is equivalent to below query performance wise(He is very confident about it)

```
Select * 
from property 
inner join tenant t on (t.hproperty = p.hmy)
inner join commtenant ct on ct.htenant = t.hmyperson
where **p.hmy = 7**
```

Could anybody help me with the explanation about why above queries are not equivalent or equivalent? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if two queries are equivalent, learn how to look at the execution plans in SQL Server Management Studio.  You can put the two queries in different windows, look at the estimated execution plans, and see for yourself if they are the same.

In this case, they probably are the same.  SQL is intended to be a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  That is, it describes the output you want, but the SQL engine is allowed to rewrite the query to be as efficient as possible.  The two forms you have describe the same output.  Do note that if there were a `left outer join` instead of an `inner join`, then the queries would be different.

In all likelihood, the engine will read the table and filter the records during the read *or* use an index for the read.  The key idea, though, is that the output is the same and SQL Server can recognize this.

Comment: Ran Actual execution plan and checked the difference. Everything is same. As you said SQL engine rewrote the query to make it efficient. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"p.hmy = 7" is not a join condition, as it relates only to a single table. As such, it doesn't really belong in the ON clause of the join. Since you are not adding any information by placing the condition in the ON clause, having it in the WHERE clause (in which it really belongs) will not make any difference to the query plan generated. If in doubt, look at the query plans.